# Problems rendering a sword

Tags: rendering

I want to render the sword I just finished.  But when I render it, the hilt and handle are fine but the blade looks odd.  Why is this?

Here is the render:

[image: Rendered]

This is what the blade looks like in object mode:

[image: Object Mode]

This is what it looks like in edit mode:

[image: Edit Mode]

This is my lighting setup:

[image: Lightning Setup]

I'm supposed to have the bevel along the sword but not what I have highlighted below.

[image: Problem Areas]

Comment: Have you removed doubles and recalculated normals? If it won't help, feel free to post a .blend file via http://pasteall.org/, so we can see what's the problem.

Comment: I clicked removed doubles but didn't have any and reset my normals but it didn't change, here's a link to the model.

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33906 and the password to it is : render

Comment: @Sam Some of the liks in your question are broken. And please link images directly to the question instead of sending us to websites plagued with adds.

Comment: @cegaton I did not see any adds, https://adblockplus.org really does work.

Comment: the links work its just as i dont have 10 rep on this site i cant do more than two links on this site so there will be a ! before the link, remove that and there may be a space between the http:// and the rest of the link close that and the link should work

Comment: Please use the Blender Stackexchange [built-in tool](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/add-images-to-stack-exchange-questions) to provide images. Images on tinypic and other services tend to vanish, so your question and possible answers will be useless.

Answer (score 5):

Alrighty, lets jump into it.

First of all, those weird spots in the render were perfectly normal. If you zoom in, you'll see that they're actually triangles- this from the fact that all n-gons are actually sets of tris. You can solve this by adding a *subdivision-surface* modifier.

Now you don't have those triangles, but you get a different effect: looks like quicksilver.

[image]

Now, this is mostly just a modeling error because two sides of the blade converge momentarily in the center, the area of the sword commonly called the *bloodlet*. This creates a zooky effect that is the combo of z-fighting and bad unwrapping.

To fix, I changed the subsurf mod from *catmull-clark* to *simple*.

[image]

You still get a bit of whack, so go into modeling and put some air between the inside edges of the bloodlet, rather than allowing it to be 2D. Then unwrap the model. This should fix everything. It needed to be unwrapped because your texture was repeating to much in the bloodlet because there were more vertices then around the rest of the blade.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!, now i was finally able to finish this portfolio piece! just so you can see here is the finished product! http://tinypic.com/r/2ahy54l/8 looks just how i imagined! :>

Comment: The render looks good now. There is still some place for geometry improvements though (as Vince suggested). Btw if this answer helped you, feel free to mark it as accepted using the check mark at the top left of the post.